# powershell get samaccountuser with no formatting

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I write a powershell command to return the `samaccountname`, and I kind of get what I want but not exactly.

```
PS C:\> (get-aduser -Server -f {(GivenName -eq "Nota") -and (Surname -eq "Realuser")} -Properties SamAccountName | select SamAccountName)
```

This is what I get:

```
SamAccountName

--------------
NRealuser
```

This is what I want:

```
NRealuser
```

So I want the `samaccountname` without the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the `ExpandProperty` parameter that `Select-Object` offers.

```
(Get-ADUser -Server -f {(GivenName -eq "Nota") -and (Surname -eq "Realuser")} -Properties SamAccountName | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName)
```

You could also have skipped the `Select-Object` part and just retrieved the value of the property in the "normal way" like this:

```
(Get-ADUser -Server -f {(GivenName -eq "Nota") -and (Surname -eq "Realuser")} -Properties SamAccountName).SamAccountName
```

Comment: SamAccountName is returned by default and so you should not have to specify `-Properties SamAccountName`. As stated by @frode-f, the ExpandProperty parameter is exactly what you needed.